# Linq-to-Sql: How to specify condition that checks for value contained in some pool but has an extra value associated that needs to be checked

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, dictionary

Ok, its difficult to explain it in the title above. So here it is hopefully clearer:

Say I have a pool of document numbers and their associated areas (DocNum, Area):
(AB, 1), (GH, 2), (UI, 3)

Now I want to write a Linq-to-Sql query to retrieve information of all the documents with that combination of values from a database, how should I do that? Because I thought it could be done using a dictionary:

```
var data = from document in context.documents
           where dictionary.Contains(new KeyValuePair(document.DocNum, document.Area))
           select new
           {
               ...whatever
           }
```

If I try to do it like this then I get the following error:

> System.NotSupportedException: The member
>   'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,Area].Key'
>   has no supported translation to SQL.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

The LINQ to SQL has no way of representing the in-memory `Dictionary` lookup as SQL. One way around that is to use `AsEnumerable` to ensure you are using LINQ to Objects instead:

```
var data = from document in context.documents.AsEnumerable()
       where dictionary.Contains(new KeyValuePair(document.DocNum, document.Area))
       select new
       {
           ...whatever
       }
```

Note that this will effectively mean you are fetching **every** row from the `context.documents`. If it's a small table, this shouldn't be a problem, but for a large table you should consider doing this kind of filtering server-side, directly in SQL - e.g. by replacing the client-side `Dictionary` with a server-side table (that you can JOIN with `documents`), possibly even a temporary table (depending on your needs).

**--- EDIT ---**

**If** the `Dictionary` is small and the table is large but well indexed, it might be worth executing a separate query for each value being searched. For example:

```
class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        var criteria = new Dictionary<KeyValuePair<string, string>, object> {
            { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("n1", "a1"), null },
            { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("n2", "a2"), null },
            { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("n3", "a3"), null },
        };

        using (var ctx = new DataClasses1DataContext()) {

            ctx.Log = Console.Out;

            var rows = new List<Document>();
            foreach (var criterion in criteria.Keys) {

                var q = from document in ctx.Documents
                    where document.DocNum == criterion.Key && document.Area == criterion.Value
                    select document;

                rows.AddRange(q);

            }

            foreach (var row in rows)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", row.DocNum, row.Area);

        }

    }

}
```

This prints the following output:

```
SELECT [t0].[DocNum], [t0].[Area]
FROM [dbo].[Document] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[DocNum] = @p0) AND ([t0].[Area] = @p1)
-- @p0: Input NVarChar (Size = 4000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [n1]
-- @p1: Input NVarChar (Size = 4000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [a1]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.1

SELECT [t0].[DocNum], [t0].[Area]
FROM [dbo].[Document] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[DocNum] = @p0) AND ([t0].[Area] = @p1)
-- @p0: Input NVarChar (Size = 4000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [n2]
-- @p1: Input NVarChar (Size = 4000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [a2]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.1

SELECT [t0].[DocNum], [t0].[Area]
FROM [dbo].[Document] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[DocNum] = @p0) AND ([t0].[Area] = @p1)
-- @p0: Input NVarChar (Size = 4000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [n3]
-- @p1: Input NVarChar (Size = 4000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [a3]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.1

n1, a1
n2, a2
n3, a3
```

Note however that this wastes `Dictionary`'s innate search capabilities (it might just as well be any other `IEnumerable`) and performs very badly if there are many dictionary elements.

Answer (score 0):

Contains can use a simple array of single values and translate that to a `Where x In {a,b,c}` clause in SQL. I don't think Where...In can support multiple columns in SQL. As a result, you really need a join or complex where (SQL - 82 style). You can join a object collection to a table (but not a table to an object collection) as follows:

```
var data = from dict in dictionary.Values
           join document in context.documents 
           on new {dict.DocNum, dict.Area} equals new {document.DocNum, document.Area}
           select new {};
```

However, this will require that the entire documents table be pulled into memory and the join then being done via LINQ to Objects.

Comment: FYI, Oracle supports multiple columns in IN, though most other databases don't. In any case, most databases have limitations on the size of the SQL statement and the size of `IN (...)` list itself (for example Oracle allows no more than 1000 items in this list).

Comment: SQL Server has a similar limitation on the number of in parameters. Since the OP is using LINQ to SQL, I assume it is hitting SQL Server not Oracle in this case, but good to know about the difference.